# npm on windows does not recognize installed modules

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

While npm is working (i'm using recent official build on Windows 7) and modules are getting installed, "npm ls installed" shows empty list, so does "npm ls -g installed"
I've tried to set NODE_PATH variable to various paths, that does not seem to work either.

```
mkdir c:\temp
cd c:\temp
npm install yeti
```

[...] - everything looks good, yeti is installed

```
npm ls installed

C:\temp
└── (empty)
```

Comment: can you update with what messages you're getting or any errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command you want to run is `npm ls` or `npm ls -g` (leave off `installed`).

Comment: thanks! silly me, don't know where i got this "installed" from (i guess some old article)